# Set file name in internal zip file in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am currently working on a file zipping in camel.
I have faced some issues with the internal filename in the ZIP file. I am trying to set up the file name in the header but the file name is set up to my overall zip file (myfilename.zip). After I extracted the zip file and file exists with MessageID.txt. I want to set up a file name for my internal files of zip as well.
Can anyone help me with this?

```html
<to uri="amq:queue:INLET"/> <!--QUEUE TO FILE-->
  <setHeader name="FileName">
   <simple>myfilename</simple>
  </setHeader>
  <marshal>
    <zipfile/> 
  </marshal>          
<to uri="file:C:/Target/?fileName=${header.FileName}.zip"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The header name should be `CamelFileName`, not `FileName`.

Per documentation: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/dataformats/zipfile-dataformat.html#_marshal